# Getting Vendor ID and Product ID from Winusb

Tags: c#, usb, winusb

I am trying to get the Vendor and Product IDs from a Winusb device and am getting accessviolationexception when trying to use the winusb_GetDesicriptor() and cannot figure out why I am getting that exception.

Here are my declarations:

```
    internal devInfo myDevInfo = new devInfo();
    USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR ifaceDescriptor;
    USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR deviceDescriptor;


    internal struct USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR
    {
        internal Byte bLength;
        internal Byte bDescriptorType;
        internal Byte bInterfaceNumber;
        internal Byte bAlternateSetting;
        internal Byte bNumEndpoints;
        internal Byte bInterfaceClass;
        internal Byte bInterfaceSubClass;
        internal Byte bInterfaceProtocol;
        internal Byte iInterface;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 18, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]internal byte bLength;
        [FieldOffset(1)]internal byte bDescriptorType;
        [FieldOffset(2)]internal ushort bcdUSB;
        [FieldOffset(4)]internal byte bDeviceClass;
        [FieldOffset(5)]internal byte bDeviceSubClass;
        [FieldOffset(6)]internal byte bDeviceProtocol;
        [FieldOffset(7)]internal byte bMaxPacketSize0;
        [FieldOffset(8)]internal ushort idVendor;
        [FieldOffset(10)]internal ushort idProduct;
        [FieldOffset(12)]internal ushort bcdDevice;
        [FieldOffset(14)]internal byte iManufacturer;
        [FieldOffset(15)]internal byte iProduct;
        [FieldOffset(16)]internal byte iSerialNumber;
        [FieldOffset(17)]internal byte bNumConfigurations;
    }

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern Boolean WinUsb_Initialize(SafeFileHandle DeviceHandle, ref IntPtr InterfaceHandle);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern Boolean WinUsb_QueryInterfaceSettings(IntPtr InterfaceHandle, Byte AlternateInterfaceNumber, ref USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR UsbAltInterfaceDescriptor);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern Boolean WinUsb_GetDescriptor(IntPtr InterfaceHandle, byte DescriptorType, byte Index, ushort LanguageID, ref USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR UsbAltDeviceDescriptor, ulong BufferLength, ref long LengthTransferred);
```

And then here is the code I am trying to run:

```
deviceHandle = CreateFile
                   (devicePathName,
                   (GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ),
                   FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                   IntPtr.Zero,
                   OPEN_EXISTING,
                   FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                   0);

            success = WinUsb_Initialize(deviceHandle, ref myDevInfo.winUsbHandle);
            success = WinUsb_QueryInterfaceSettings(myDevInfo.winUsbHandle, 0, ref ifaceDescriptor);
            success = WinUsb_GetDescriptor(myDevInfo.winUsbHandle,
                           0x01,
                           (byte)deviceIndex,
                           0,
                           ref deviceDescriptor,
                           18,
                           ref lengthTransferred);
```

I am getting through the initialize and getting the values back from queryinterfacesettings, but getting the accessviolation on the GetDescriptor call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [documentation for `WinUsb_GetDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It looks like your parameters are not correct. To obtain the VID/PID, which is in the Device Descriptor, you will want to specify the `USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE` type for the second parameter (0x01). You also only need to specify the language ID if you are requesting a String Descriptor. The length for your device descriptor is wrong too, it should be 18 (`ushort` is 2 bytes, this is probably the reason for your access violation). You also want to use `byte` instead of `Byte` in your `DeviceDescriptor` struct, you don't want the .NET class representation of the byte, just the type value itself.

Here is updated code that may work for you:

```
success = WinUsb_GetDescriptor(myDevInfo.winUsbHandle,
                               0x01, 
                               (byte)deviceIndex,
                               0,
                               ref deviceDescriptor,
                               18,
                               ref lengthTransferred);
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips and suggestions, I implemented them and am unfortunately still getting accessviolation exception. I have updated my initial question with your changes as well.

Comment: Double check your marshaling on the struct, maybe using the StructLayout will help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef4c3t39.aspx

Comment: Aside from having the imports in a struct, what is the difference in how I am doing it as opposed to that way?

Comment: Using StructLayout forces the memory to be laid out in a specified way. Since you are in managed code this is not always the case. Going from managed to unmanaged code is tricky. Again, take a look at the documenation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, I tried implementing the StructLayout as you suggested and still get the accessviolation, I have updated my code above, is that the correct implementation in c#?

Comment: It's probably something in your marshaling still - try using the following DLL import, which uses byte[] instead of the ref to your struct: `[DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)] private static extern bool WinUsb_GetDescriptor(IntPtr InterfaceHandle, byte DescriptorType, byte Index, UInt16 LanguageID, byte[] Buffer, UInt32 BufferLength, out UInt32 LengthTransfered);`

Comment: that last suggestion worked. Thank you for the help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class for USB calls including helper code for getting other descriptor information.

```
public static partial class WinUsbApiCalls
{
    #region Constants
    public const int EnglishLanguageID = 1033;
    public const uint DEVICE_SPEED = 1;
    public const byte USB_ENDPOINT_DIRECTION_MASK = 0X80;
    public const byte WritePipeId = 0x80;

    /// <summary>
    /// Not sure where this constant is defined...
    /// </summary>
    public const int DEFAULT_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE = 0x01;
    public const int USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE = 0x03;
    #endregion

    #region API Calls
    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_ControlTransfer(IntPtr InterfaceHandle, WINUSB_SETUP_PACKET SetupPacket, byte[] Buffer, uint BufferLength, ref uint LengthTransferred, IntPtr Overlapped);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_GetAssociatedInterface(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte AssociatedInterfaceIndex, out SafeFileHandle AssociatedInterfaceHandle);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_GetDescriptor(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte DescriptorType, byte Index, ushort LanguageID, out USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR deviceDesc, uint BufferLength, out uint LengthTransfered);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_GetDescriptor(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte DescriptorType, byte Index, UInt16 LanguageID, byte[] Buffer, UInt32 BufferLength, out UInt32 LengthTransfered);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_Free(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_Initialize(SafeFileHandle DeviceHandle, out SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_QueryDeviceInformation(IntPtr InterfaceHandle, uint InformationType, ref uint BufferLength, ref byte Buffer);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_QueryInterfaceSettings(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte AlternateInterfaceNumber, out USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR UsbAltInterfaceDescriptor);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_QueryPipe(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte AlternateInterfaceNumber, byte PipeIndex, out WINUSB_PIPE_INFORMATION PipeInformation);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_ReadPipe(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte PipeID, byte[] Buffer, uint BufferLength, out uint LengthTransferred, IntPtr Overlapped);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_SetPipePolicy(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte PipeID, uint PolicyType, uint ValueLength, ref uint Value);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_WritePipe(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte PipeID, byte[] Buffer, uint BufferLength, out uint LengthTransferred, IntPtr Overlapped);
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public static string GetDescriptor(SafeFileHandle defaultInterfaceHandle, byte index, string errorMessage)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[256];
        var isSuccess = WinUsb_GetDescriptor(defaultInterfaceHandle, USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE, index, EnglishLanguageID, buffer, (uint)buffer.Length, out var transfered);
        WindowsDeviceBase.HandleError(isSuccess, errorMessage);
        var descriptor = new string(Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(buffer, 2, (int)transfered));
        return descriptor.Substring(0, descriptor.Length - 1);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

[Usage](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/1a5c2073fe2ae2b50fe2bd9ab2fbeae413cf85aa/src/Usb.Net/Windows/WindowsUsbDeviceFactory.cs#L62)

```
        var isSuccess2 = WinUsbApiCalls.WinUsb_GetDescriptor(defaultInterfaceHandle, WinUsbApiCalls.DEFAULT_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE, 0, WinUsbApiCalls.EnglishLanguageID, out var _UsbDeviceDescriptor, bufferLength, out var lengthTransferred);
```

The code comes from [here](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/master/src/Usb.Net/Windows/WinUsbApiCalls.cs) and is part of the [Usb.Net](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/tree/master/src/Usb.Net) framework. To connect to enumerate through and get USB devices with it, you can see the [wiki](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/wiki/Enumerating-Connected-Devices).